# Wowza s3 upload plugin not uploading to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, wowza

[Wowza S3 Upload Plugin](https://github.com/WowzaMediaSystems/wse-plugin-s3upload)

I have followed all the steps written in https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?813-How-to-upload-recorded-media-to-an-Amazon-S3-bucket-%28ModuleS3Upload%29#requirements guide but no .upload files are being created and hence no files have been uploaded to S3.

I have manually tried to upload to S3 successfully.

Below are my settings for module section 
[image]

and these are my custom properties
[image]

Both the above configuration changes are on this page

[http://localhost:8088/enginemanager/Home.htm#application/*defaultVHost*/live/live/main](http://localhost:8088/enginemanager/Home.htm#application/_defaultVHost_/live/live/main)

I am using Wowza Streaming Engine 4.4.1 and AWS JAVA SDK 1.11.5

What is that I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have copied the 3 `*.jar`s you need into the `[install-dir]/lib` directory.

1. [wse-plugin-s3upload.zip](https://www.wowza.com/downloads/forums/collection/wse-plugin-s3upload.zip)
   (unzip and copy the `*.jar`)
2. [AWS Java SDK For Amazon
   S3](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3/1.10.77/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.10.77.jar)
3. [AWS SDK For Java
   Core](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/1.10.77/aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.77.jar)

Be sure to restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

I never used "Wowza S3 Upload Plugin", but you might be able to accomplish the same (and maybe in an easier way) by mounting your bucket into a s3fs filesystem then make uploads by copying files to that path.

Here's the details:

https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?72-How-to-use-the-FUSE-based-file-system-backed-by-Amazon-S3

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Make sure the IAM user credentials you create have access to write to the s3 bucket.

When you initially create that IAM user, there is not permissions set.

[image]